# how to refresh index page without reloading browser using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

the desire i want is similar on how facebook works; when a new content is being published, it pushes down the old post with the new posts on top.

- New Content (pushes down previous topics without reloading the page)
- Old Content 1
- Old Content 2
- Old Content 3

is that possible in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The used term for this is "infinite scroll", there are plugins that may assist you to achieve this behavior, you can check this one: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/

Answer (score 0):

If the infinity scoll plugin not working (what a great opportunity, because it comes from a very unstable extension), try ["Jetpack"](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) which is also included in this function and only requires very little configuration, encore is stable, never have a problem with it:

Add this code for the funcktions.php:

`function zilla_infinite_scroll_render() {

}

get_template_part( 'content-post', 'standard' );

add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(

'container' => 'content',

'render' => 'zilla_infinite_scroll_render',

));`


And change the container id your post container id. So this line must be change:
 `'container' => 'content'` (the content is my post div ID,so you must be change this).

That's it,have fun :)